# Make large text using loop cycle and dbms_lob.append method

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have in table `my_table`   column `cclloobb` which type is `CLOB`.

```
    CREATE TYPE big_text_pieces  AS VARRAY(7) OF NVARCHAR2(30000);


    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE app_to_clob(arr IN big_text_pieces)
    IS
    my_var CLOB;
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN 1..arr.COUNT LOOP
            dbms_lob.append(my_var, arr(i)  );
        END LOOP;
        UPDATE my_table SET
        cclloobb = my_var
        WHERE id = 3;
    END;
```

The procedure compiled success

Then, when I am trying call procedure

`CALL app_to_clob(  big_text_pieces('q','w','e')  );`

I got error: `numeric or value error: invalid LOB locator specified: ORA-22275`

Tell please, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`my_var` should be initialized before the first value is appended to it.

Please try this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE app_to_clob(arr IN big_text_pieces)
    IS
    my_var CLOB;
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN 1..arr.COUNT LOOP
            IF my_var IS NULL THEN
              my_var := arr(i);
            else
              dbms_lob.append(my_var, arr(i)  );
            end if;
        END LOOP;
        UPDATE my_table SET
        cclloobb = my_var
        WHERE id = 3;
    END;
```